# I have patched openssl but SSLTest and Nessus say I am still vulnerable to CVE-2014-0224

Tags: tls, openssl, vulnerability, vulnerability-scanners

I am running a server with CentOS 6.5, patched to recent openssl updates via `yum update ssl` and with indications the current version indeed has the patch to the vulnerability.

```
$ sudo rpm -q --changelog openssl | grep CVE-2014-0224
- fix CVE-2014-0224 fix that broke EAP-FAST session resumption support
- fix CVE-2014-0224 - SSL/TLS MITM vulnerability
```

However, a [SSLTest scan](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest) and Nessus indicate that I'm still vulnerable

> This server is vulnerable to the OpenSSL CCS vulnerability (CVE-2014-0224) and exploitable. Grade set to F.

I'm at a loss - should I trust SSLTest and Nessus or the Centos distro and rpm flag?

**Note**: we always restart all relevant services after patches.

Comment: is there a load balancer or any other system between qualys and your patched server that might be causing the finding? redirected ports?

Comment: In addition to checking the items @schroeder mentioned, do you possibly have a service using a statically linked version of OpenSSL, rather than the OS version?

Comment: @Xander - I have verified all openssl libraries are patched.  Both nessus and ssllabs, however, report we are vulnerable.

Comment: @schroeder nope - the server I am referring to is the front end that gets hit first.

Answer (score 1):

If openssl was patched recently and you have not restarted all services which are using libssl you may have to reboot your machine in order to complete the openssl patching.

By running following command you can see what services are using libssl:

```
lsof | grep -i libssl | grep DEL | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: OP says that reboots occured.